# How can I tell if the current result is the last result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I've got a new online store written in PHP and MySQL.

```
<div class="content-area">
<div class="page-heading">
<h1>Store</h1>
</div>
<p style="padding-top: 5px;"><strong>You are here:</strong> <a href="<?php echo $cls->root(); ?>/">Home</a> &raquo; Store</p>
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="500">
<?php
$categories=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent='0' ORDER by owner ASC, title ASC");
while($categoriesRow=mysql_fetch_array($categories)) {
$categoriesSub=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent='$categoriesRow[id]'");
?>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div class="product_list">
<div class="image_product">
<img alt="<?php echo $categoriesRow['title']; ?>" src="<?php echo $cls->truska(true); ?>/theme_section_image.gif" border="0" style="vertical-align: middle;" />
</div>
<div>
<h3 class="product"><a href="<?php echo $cls->root(); ?>/category/<?php echo $categoriesRow['permalink']; ?>/" target="_self"><?php echo $categoriesRow['title']; ?></a> <?php if(mysql_num_rows($categoriesSub) > 0) { ?>(<?php while($categoriesSubRow=mysql_fetch_array($categoriesSub)) {  }?>)<?php } ?></h3>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="dotted_line_blue" colspan="1">
<img src="<?php echo $cls->truska(true); ?>/theme_shim.gif" height="1" width="1" alt=" " />
</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
</table>
</div>
```

Where my second While loop is, I need to work out what is the last result, so I can omit a comma from my while loop.

It will show as 'Lego (Lego City, Lego Starwars,)' but I want it to show as 'Lego (Lego City, Lego Starwars)'.

How can I get if the current result is the last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by coming at it from the other direction.

Instead of appending a comma after each result except the last, try pre-pending a comma on every result except the first.

Set up a variable called `$first` outside your loop, and set it to 1. Inside the loop:

```
if ($first == 0) {
   echo ",";
} else {
    $first = 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually - I'd recommend you try @j08691's answer, too. It's a lot more elegant!

Answer (score 2):

don't add the comma if it is the first result, and add it before in all the next ones.

Answer (score 2):

Just build your array of results and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it. This takes care of any counting automatically:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use plain mysql access, look at [PDO](http://es.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Answering your question, try something like this:

```
$items = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $items[] = $row['foo'];
}
echo implode(', ', $items);
```

Comment: Because 1) security: it's very easy to make sql injection attacks. 2) it's going to be deprecated in future versions of PHP. With PDO you can use prepared statements.

Comment: it is being deprecated because it is old and unsafe.  switch now or feel the pain later!

Comment: Well, feel free to use the solution you want. It's just  recommendation. Look at: http://es.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php